# Not able to implement new google auth using google identity services in react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-identity

According to the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google , the first step involves wrapping your app in GoogleOAuthProvider

When I do this I get the following error in my console:

[image]

App.js :

[image]

Index.js where I have wrapped App in GoogleOAuthProvider:

[image]

Where am I making a mistake?